# Is lack of speed an indication that one is not cut out to study mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, advice

This is my first post on Stack Exchange, and I apologize if it is off topic, but I would really appreciate some feedback. I decided I want to give math another shot, and picked up a book called Langs Basic Mathematics and I've been really struggling with it. I find it hard to work through, and find it difficult to apply the theory I've learned to solve problems as well as writing proofs. I've spent approximately 80 hours and completed 7 chapters of the book out of 17. Is that a reasonable pace to be learning math? I'm essentially wondering whether it is worth pursuing if my pace is so slow and I'm worried that I won't be able to keep up in a formal setting.

I would really love some feedback. 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Lang's book is one of the books I recommend, but it is true it is rather concise. If I remember well (I don't have the book at hand), it has a beautiful proof of Stirling's formula, which is not usual at  this level. It is the kind of book which should be  worked with a sheet of paper and a pencil.

Comment: Everyone has his own pace. If you like what you are doing — move on. Struggling with difficulties means you are learning, which is good. If learning was easy, it wouldn't be appreciated.

Comment: My recommendation is to pick books that you can actually read and understand without great difficulty and learn from. There are a lot of hard to read mathematics books published. Skip those. Don't worry about the pace and proofs at first. Read for understanding, and problem solving. Stick to what is right for you.

Comment: @Bernard thanks for the response. Yes it is indeed. I've gone through so much paper trying to understand it. I don't recall seeing Stirling formula however.

Comment: @lisyarus I don't mind that it's hard, it's more of a time issue. I guess I'm looking for some concrete numbers for how long a 500 page textbook should take.

Comment: @HassanGarshasb It is extremely dependent on the book, your level and your presonality. For me, a 500 page book could take from days to years.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try not to worry so much and just focus on learning.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that "speed" is not a good measure at all of one's aptitude for learning math. Especially in this context. Reading a 400-500 page text book and processing all of the information it contains can take a long time. Much longer than 40 hours. Also, if there is something that seems like it is too hard to understand without spending a ton of time on it, it may just be an indication that there are some (potentially) unstated bits of background knowledge that you haven't been exposed to or learned yet. Part of the self-learning process is figuring out what those things are and finding the resources that can help you learn them.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback! The thing is, the book is supposed to be logically contained so that someone with no experience with math can prepare for calculus. Do you have any idea what a reasonable time frame for a textbook of 4 - 500 pages should be?

Comment: Well it's really hard to give specific numbers for that kind of thing (as lisyarus said). But depending on the content maybe 1-2 semesters. Obviously if you were familiar with the material it could be on the time frame of days to weeks. If you had a bunch of additional background material to learn, potentially years. I think it might be more useful for you to give us an idea of some content you don't feel comfortable with yet or what schedule you are trying to meet.

Comment: I'm working Basic Mathematics by Serge Lang: https://www.docdroid.net/K1VENuF/basic-mathematics-serge-lang.pdf. This is the one i'm worried about, it says in the book it's a 1 semester course at the university level, or a 1 year course at the high school level. My goal was to finish this at whatever pace i could by working 2 hours/day. I'm currently on chapter 6 (isometries) and i've never seen anything like it before. I find the notation and abstraction confusing. So far i've spent 20 hours for half a chapter. I don't have experience with math beyond khan academy up to algebra 1.

Comment: I see, honestly if someone had asked me what an isometey was after I had taken calculus I wouldn’t have known what it was. I can see from this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2770658/learning-about-isometry-from-serge-langs-basic-math-very-confused that while the book is called « Basic math » it is written in a very formal style that isn’t used in algebra I, algebra II, and precalculus. Khan academy is a great site and I would definitely recommend continuing watching their lectures. You can still work on learning formal math jargon in parallel.